# How to specify EC2 IP address last octet in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I could not find a way to specify the specific IP address my EC2 instance should use in a subnet.  Is there perhaps a better way of doing this?  The following snippet works perfectly and allocates an EC2 instance an IP address of 10.1.2.254, I'm just curious if anyone has a more elegant way.

"Subnet" is a parameter in format "10.1.2.0/24"

```
EC2Instance:
    Properties
        PrivateIpAddress: !Join 
                          - "."
                          - - !Select [0, !Split [".", !Ref Subnet]]
                            - !Select [1, !Split [".", !Ref Subnet]]
                            - !Select [2, !Split [".", !Ref Subnet]]
                            - "254"
```

Comment: It seems that the Subnet is being created in the same template. Is the Subnet definition hard-coded to use the same CIDR range every time (eg `10.1.2.0/24`)? If so, you could just specify `10.1.2.254`.

Comment: Thanks John, nope that subnet is a parameter that changes with every deployment.

Comment: In that case, since your snippet works, looks fine to me!